# Persistant name on Finder tabs

Tags: macos, finder, customization, tabs, third-party

I'm looking for a way to always display a label on Finder tabs instead of the current folder name, to differentiate them when folder name is not relevant.

(Long story) I use tabs to switch between several projects which are in different folders. But when I'm not at the "root" folder of a project, the name of the Finder tab is not the one of the root folder project (but the subfolder name) and I can't quickly recognize where each project is.

I'd like to attach a project name on each tab of the same window (above the window, in the toolbar, under the tab, or better, instead of the tab name).

Any idea of an app that could do that ? (It has to be displayed everytime I ⌘-tab switch on the Finder, knowing that I always have windows under the Finder's one – so no, it can't be an text on the wallpaper).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/) made the trick! (And does a lot more.)