# display partial file path on Finder tab title

Tags: macos, finder

#### Question

Is there a way to change the Finder tab title to include the name of the containing folder?

#### Problem

I work on projects that have the same standardized subfolder names (e.g., `code`), which makes it difficult to switch between projects without going through each tab to identify the containing folder.

Current state: ambiguous Finder tab titles for three *different* subfolders
[image: Ambiguous Finder tab titles for three different folders]

#### Goal

I'd like to display the containing folder name as part of the Finder tab title. Extending the example, this would look like: `projectA/code`, `projectB/code`, etc.

Ideal solution (blue text only to emphasize the change):
[image]

#### Related questions and resources

- My question is more general than [a previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312324/how-to-rename-tab-title-name-of-finder-mac) that sought to edit individual Finder tab names.
- [Displaying the path in the Finder title bar](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/show-path-finder-title-bar/) only works for the selected tab, and does not solve the problem of distinguishing Finder tabs.
- [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139790/persistant-name-on-finder-tabs) suggests a possibility with DragThing, but doesn't make it clear how to implement the solution. UPDATE: [DragThing is being retired](https://www.dragthing.com/).

Answer (score -1):

There's no mod or preference I have seen to make Finder do this. [You'll want an alternative app if this is your one and only need for productivity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11785/5472). Check out PathFinder: https://www.cocoatech.io

I find using a code editor to view folder hierarchy works much better. If you don’t have an IDE I would start with an extensible / feature-full editor like Visual Studio Code.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/

That or making the jump to shell where you can exert exceptional control over prompts allow more customization than Finder does at present.

Answer (score -4):

Use the app "Onyx". It's free and you can use it to customize macOS. Go to Settings > Finder and there is a box for showing what you want ;)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. In other words, Onyx cannot do as asked in the OP.